# Why does the this keyword not work within an each statement?

Tags: jquery

In other words, why does this work, referencing the `video` tag again:

```
$("video").each(function(index, value) { 
    console.log($('video')[index].currentTime); 
});
```

But this example throws an error when using the `this` keyword?

```
$("video").each(function(index, value) { 
    console.log($(this)[index].currentTime); 
});
```

What is a better way to write this statement?

Comment: Did you try to debug and look at the type of `this`? Did you read the first paragraph of the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/) on `.each()`?

Answer (score 1):

Because `$(this)` in your code returns a collection with length of 1, only the first iteration will work in  your code, as the `index` is `0`.

There is no need to create a jQuery collection, you have a reference to the element by using the `this` keyword. Simply use `this.currentTime`.

Comment: the length isn't always 1, but in his case it probably is.

Comment: @true The length here is always 1. As the callback is called by jQuery `.each()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. At first read, it seemed like you were implying the collection with always be a length 1 regardless of his code, in general, but I knew that you didn't mean that. Just wanted to help out readers that may have gotten confused.

Answer (score 0):

`this` already refers to the element you want. If currentTime is a property of your object, then this will work. You can either use `value` or `this` to refer to the object.

> [The callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$("video").each(function(index, value) { 
    console.log(this.currentTime); 
});
```